# Consolidate redundant code in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, refactoring

Is there a more elegant or efficient way to write some of my code?

In particular, I have a toolstrip on all of my forms. Each form has its own set of methods that essentially is doing the same thing. Is there a way to delete all of the methods save one, and then just enclose it into a switch statement for my form specific variables?

An example of what I am talking about:

```
'Form 1
Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub

'Form 2
Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Could I delete one of them, and move the other to a separate module and have it act for both form1 and form2?

```
    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles [myWholeDangProject].ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use Addhandler and AddressOf to hookup the events when the forms initialize.

```
AddHandler ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click, AddressOf MyModule.ExitHandler
```

and

```
Public Sub ExitHandler(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! After seeing my options I am not sure if this is the route I want to take.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to direct a WithEvents event to a shared module. Like you say, though, a shared class or VB.NET module can hold subroutines that can be called from both control event handlers.

You *could* make a shared event handler, but you have to use the [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) keyword to actually attach the code to the event though in most simple cases just a straight call to a sub would be easier.